# Java - Inheritance Issue

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

I got a problem as I have been recently trying to write my own "library" with different well-known data structures such as linked lists, trees, tries, heaps, etc.

Sadly, I got stuck while coding the first one (the linked list). For that, I wrote a "Node" class (separate file), and a "Linked List" class, which "extends" the "Node" class (in order to use it as a reference object).
Long story short, here is my code so far:

"Node.java"

```
package helper;

public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private Node<T> next;

    protected Node(T newValue) {
        value = newValue;
        next = null;
    }

    protected void printNode() {
        System.out.print("{" + value + "} ");
    }
}
```

"LinkedList.java"

```
package source;

import helper.Node;

public class LinkedList<T> extends Node<T> {
    private Node<T> head, current;

    protected LinkedList(T newValue) {
        super(newValue);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm not even half-way done, but what I don't understand, is why on C++ (coded in C++ for like 4 years and only recently started java) I don't have to define a constructor which makes a "super()" call, like calling the constructor of the derived class, but on Java, I have to do that..

All I want to do, is use the "Node" class to create "Node" objects in the "LinkedList" class.. I don't want the "LinkedList" constructor to call the "Node" constructor (we should have an empty Linked List after constructor is called).

Sorry if I sound a little confusing, but hope you understood what I wanted to say. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Please don't tell me to use the Java built-in libraries, as I am doing this just for practice.

Comment: Simple: don't make `LinkedList` extend `Node`. It doesn't make sense: a linked list *is not a* node, a linked list *has* nodes! You don't need to inherit from `Node` in order to be able to use it.

Comment: I don't understand your design. Why does a `LinkedList` have an **is-a**-relationship to a `Node`?

Comment: Sorry for that, understood it now.. I don't know why I thought that to be able to use the Node class in Java I had to call it as a derived class.. Well.. In C++ things are a little different, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LinkedList` structure should *contain* a `Node`, not *be* a `Node`.  In Java, you always have to explicitly call the super constructor if a no-arg constructor is not provided.  Whenever you create an object, all superclasses constructors are called in order from most generic, to most specific so in this case, the `Node` constructor would be called first before the `LinkedList` constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know what was in my mind when I wrote that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer composition over inheritance in this case. Right now your LinkedList [isA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) Node and since Node has just single constructor that takes value, you have to call super(value).

Also you can use [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) from java.util package (don't reinvent the wheel here).

Comment: Thanks, but you see, I am not reinventing the wheel, if you simply read my full post, you saw that I said it is for practice.